# Ubuntu 22.04 Pulseaudio not seeing my connected headphones

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Common issue, but nothing I have found has worked (see below)

I can connect the headphones instantly, but, I never get the "Bluetooth connected" voice in my ear, so it may not be a proper connection (I get this message when connecting to the phone, other computers etc).

The headphones show as connected in BlueMan, with the coloured bars for link quality etc.

In the BlueMan Device menu, Audio Profile does nothing.

Important to note - Bluetooth audio has worked before, and I don't believe I did anything to change it (before I started trying to fix things, obvously).

sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover gives me
Failure: Module initialisation failed

under lsmod, I have, for Bluetooth
bluetooth [size] btrl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm

The latest bluez is installed, but I can't see what it does or where it does it.

What I would like are more diagnostic tools - what can I check for, which installed modules, whether they are set up correctly (I'm interested in validating A2DP, for example). I don't know where else to look. Is there a comprehensive write up of it that I could check up? A walk through of what needs to be installed where, for it to work?

I have:
Removed alsa-base pulseaudio and reinstalled
Checked for pulseaudio-bluetooth
Chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/
Added AutoConnect A2DP to bluetooth/main.conf
Removed load-module module-blutooth-discover from default.pa to x11

and all kinds of other things that I've lost track of.